# PUT ou PATCH, qual devo usar nesse cenário

Tags: rest

Tenho uma base de dados hipotética:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    code integer NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

Quando realizo um POST, crio enviando no body:

```
{
    "code": 15,
    "name": "John"
}
```

Como podem ver, o **code** é uma chave primária, ou seja, não poderei criar mais de uma linha com o mesmo code.

Quando realizo um PUT (*endpoint/person/{code}*) eu envio o mesmo body do post, porém, não irei atualizar o code, apenas o name. Quando é enviado o code diferente do que é enviado no endpoint, apenas ignoro o que vem no body e considero o que vem no endpoint.

Minha dúvida é, essa forma que faço pode ser considerado um PUT, ou eu deveria utilizar o PATCH ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferença entre o PUT e o PATCH é meramente semântica. Ou seja, o sentido que a requisição possui: seu objetivo.

Uma característica interessante do método PUT é que ele atualiza um registro existente, mas cria um novo caso inexistente. Ou seja, ao enviar o "code" e o "name" através de uma requisição PUT, mas o "code" ainda não existir no banco de dados, o mesmo será criado. Por isso, não faria muito sentido você informar o "code" via URL.

Mas qual seria a diferença entre o PUT e o POST?

A idempotência. Enquanto no método POST ao fazer inúmeras requisições idênticas seguidas seria criado inúmeros registros, no método PUT seria criado apenas um. A primeira requisição criaria o registro e todas as subsequentes apenas atualizariam o registro existente com os mesmos dados - ou seja, não seria alterado.

No seu caso, se a ideia é informar o "code" via URL apenas com o intuito de atualizá-lo, o PATCH faz mais sentido. Mas uma premissa do PATCH é que ele pode fazer alterações parciais do registro, considerando estruturas com mais de uma coluna. Parece não ser seu caso.

Em resumo:

- Use o PATCH se:

  - Informar o "code" via URL;
  - Se o "code" não existir, irá dar erro;
  - For permitido atualizações parciais do recurso;
- Use o PUT se:

  - Informar o "code" via corpo da requisição;
  - Se o "code" não existir, será criado;
  - Não for permitido atualizações parciais do recurso;

Detalhe: os métodos não são exclusivos entre si, você pode muito bem implementar ambos e tirar o máximo proveito da sua API.